# Broadcast rtmps stream to many servers

Tags: ssl, nginx, streaming, rtmp

The data flow is : user --send media rtmp--> server A --> server B,C,D.

Now, I'm using nginx+rtmp module in server A and config `push` to server B,C,D. 
But nginx+rtmp module don't support push rtmps at this time. Any other options ?